# Error while trying to create another MySQL instance on a server

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error while trying to install the new MySQL service "**[ERROR] [MY-000074] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Empty value for 'table_open_cache' specified.**" , i've increased the table_open_cache size yet no success. Anyone has a fix to this? i'll appreciate.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: can you elaborate what you did or which tutorial you used

Comment: also show your mysql error log

Comment: Make sure your second instance picks up the correct configuration file.

Comment: there is a good guide at mysql website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: i used this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbWmjdWTO8E&t=237s
basically i 
1. Created  new folder for the new instance
2. copy my.ini file from old instance to new instance.
3. Edit new my.ini file to change the below.
 - Port (all entries)
 - server-id (all entries)
 - data-dir path to reflect new "Data" folder in newly crated instance folder
4. Open CMD as admin then Cd to bin folder C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
5. then run  
i also tried in on my personal computer and it worked fine.